# CSS Best Practice: Adding modifying classes, or creating whole new classes

Tags: css

I find myself slightly changing how I'm writing my css at the moment, and I'm not sure if it's for the better or worse.
Imagine I have a class `container`

```
.container { display: block; border: 1px solid red; padding: 20px; height: 400px; }
```

Now lets say in places I also want a smaller container of say 150px height. What is the best way to go about this?

Previously I would have made a class:

```
.container-small { display: block; border: 1px solid red; padding: 20px; height: 150px; }
```

However, obviously there is now replication in my css file. So recently I have started using modifier classes like `small` and adding it in the HTML beside `container` and adding it to the css file like so:

```
.container.small { height: 150px }
```

The issue I can forsee with this is, if I have another class like `banner`, and I add the `small` class to that but to make it 90px height, that could be confusing to someone else looking at my project? As `small` is doing different things in different places. Is this already an accepted paradigm, or should I use new classes each time in a similar way to how I was using `small` but with new names for each class.

```
.container-small { height: 150px }
```

and

```
.banner-small { height: 90px }
```

I like the simplicity of just adding `small`, `big`, `wide` or whatever modifying classes to each element, but are there any concrete reasons why this would be a bad idea? I presume it's slightly slower using modifying classes like that as the css will target a load of `small` tags before discarding them due to being beside the wrong element, but presumably that's a negligible amount.

What is the best practice?

Comment: Have you looked at BEM? It's one of the more popular methodologies for naming classes in HTML and CSS - http://getbem.com/introduction/

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: You can use sass with BEM  for more structured and organised code.
there are features like placeholders and mixins are available to extend the desirable properties to modify a specific class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start with reading about CSS methodologies. There are 3 different methodologies OOCSS, BEM, SMACSS,  at least, they are the most popular. You can start, for example, with this [article](http://codetheory.in/an-overview-of-oocss-bem-smacss/)

Answer (score 0):

Best practise changes by the year and by who you talk to but a common paradign is to use name spaces like

`.container .container-small {}`

Personally though I do

`.container.small {}`

and then nest it using Less or SASS to keep it readable.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should separated the classes like

banner where you would only place the text size, color and type

small will have only the size and maybe border colors and size

container will have the same has above with the flex container properties

etc etc et

```
class="banner small"
class="container big"
class="inside_container small"
```